# Auth service with jwt and Vault

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, java-web-start, vault

I want to implement a small authorization service on JWT tokens
My steps :

1. Tokens will be signed by the RSA
2. Store keys I want to delegate to Vault, and I want Vault to automatically generate new keys
3. Authorization Service will pull the current private key from Vault, release jwt token with jku header (url public key in Vault) and kid header (public key ID)
4. The verification service goes to Vault and with jku and kid gets the actual public key, then validates the token

How relevant and appropriate is such a scheme ? Does Vault have such a case for its use ?